# Knockoutjs - Transitions between dynamic template switching?

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

KnockoutJS has been really great to use so far, but I'm new to the framework. I'm trying to create a tabbed sort of interface, e.g. 4 links and a common display area. Clicking on a link takes advantage of Knockout's templating system and will switch the template. This has been working great, but I want to add some kind of animation in between the template switching.

How can I accomplish this? I've read a little bit about beforeRemove/afterAdd, but this only seems to apply to observableArrays.  I know KnockoutJS supports animations/custom bindings (I'm using them more straightforwardly for other elements on my page).

If my whole approach is incorrect, is there a better way to do a tabbed interface to easily get transitions?

Here is my code right now.

The HTML:

```
<div class="Page">
    <span data-bind="template: {name: current_page()}"></span>
</div>
<script type="text/html" id="Home">
    <!-- Home content -->
</script>
<script type="text/html" id="Tab1">
    <!-- Tab1 content -->
</script>
```

The Javascript (Knockout's ViewModel):

```
this.current_page  = ko.observable("Home")
//later on...
this.current_page("Tab1");
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `afterRender` property of the [template binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html):

```
<span data-bind="template: {name: current_page(), afterRender: animatePageChange }"></span>
```

.. and then on your view model you can add whatever animation you fancy:

```
animatePageChange: function() { $('#content').hide(); $('#content').fadeIn(3000); }
```

I have put together a simple demo at http://jsfiddle.net/unklefolk/v3JMS/1/

Comment: Would there be a clean way to do this with a custom binding? I've seen `fadeVisible` and `slideVisible` bindings but the problem with using them in a wizard / workflow is that you only want to show the new template after the current template has been hidden

Comment: Great answer and thanks for the jsFiddle.  I added some simple toggling logic so you can keep pressing the button to see the transition multiple times without having to reload the page.  Updated jsFiddle here:  http://jsfiddle.net/v3JMS/12/

Comment: @ClearCloud8, updated external resources on that [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v3JMS/52/)